# CSS not linking to Html when linking bootstrap and JS files

Tags: html, css

```css
#title
{
    background-color: #ff4c68;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TinDog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="StyleSheet1.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <section id="title">

        <!-- Nav Bar -->
        <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Title -->

        <div>
            <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
            <button type="button">Download</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>

    </section>


    <!-- Features -->

    <section id="features">

        <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
        <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>

        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>

        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>

    </section>


    <!-- Testimonials -->

    <section id="testimonials">

        <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
        <img src="dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
        <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

        <!-- <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
        <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
        <em>Beverly, Illinois</em> -->

    </section>


    <!-- Press -->

    <section id="press">
        <img src="techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
        <img src="tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
        <img src="bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
        <img src="mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

    </section>


    <!-- Pricing -->

    <section id="pricing">

        <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
        <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>


        <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
        <h2>Free</h2>
        <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
        <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
        <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


        <h3>Labrador</h3>
        <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
        <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
        <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
        <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


        <h3>Mastiff</h3>
        <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
        <p>Pirority Listing</p>
        <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
        <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
        <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

    </section>


    <!-- Call to Action -->

    <section id="cta">

        <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
        <button type="button">Download</button>
        <button type="button">Download</button>

    </section>


    <!-- Footer -->

    <footer id="footer">

        <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>

    </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

It's running in the snippet and when I run the same code in sublime text , it works . But in visual studio 2019 , it does not work. The css is not working . Kindly help resolve the issue. In Visual studio , when I make a few file , it's getting linked but whnen I have added bootstap and JS files , it does not implement the CSS file.

Comment: Add your custom css in the last

Comment: Make sure that you have the correct stylesheet name because I have tested it on codepen and vs code and it works.

Comment: Locate your custom stylesheet bellow all libraries stylesheets, to avoid any overwriting for your code, and make sure the correct path and name of your style file.